# How can i change data format using with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

```
{"Adana, Türkiye", "Mersin, Akdeniz/Mersin, Türkiye", "Yozgat, Yozgat Merkez/Yozgat, Türkiye"}
```

How can I convert this data format to array?

For example:

```
["Adana, Türkiye",
 "Mersin, Akdeniz/Mersin, Türkiye",
 "Yozgat, Yozgat Merkez/Yozgat, Türkiye"]
```

I tried many methods but none worked. I do not think I saw any easy methods to do this.

Comment: *"I tried many method but all didn't work."* Mind to share, what you tried?

Comment: As the first is neither valid JSON nor valid javascript, *what* is it? A string?

Comment: @derpirscher I think he is not claiming that he has a JSON. It's just formatted data. But sharing what has been tried, and what didn't work would be nice.

Comment: @eldar Yes, but to be able to help, we need to know, what it actually is. Because if it's a string, you could just replace `{}` with `[]` and do a `JSON.parse`

Comment: @derpirscher Actually the first line is a block of code containing three string values separated by comma operators which evaluates to the last string expression. `eval('{"one", "two", "three"}')` actually returns "three", which confused me until I remembered `eval` returns the last value it calculated :-)

Comment: @traktor Yeah, but as OP is speaking of a "data-format", I excluded that option ...

Answer (score 1):

If your `data` is just a simple string and does not contain any other `{}` than the starting and ending ones, you could simply do

```js
let data = '{"Adana, Türkiye","Mersin, Akdeniz/Mersin, Türkiye","Yozgat, Yozgat Merkez/Yozgat, Türkiye"}';

let d = JSON.parse(`[${data.replace(/[{}]/g, "")}]`);
console.log(d);
```

I.e., replace the curly braces `{}` with square brackets `[]` and do a `JSON.parse`

Answer (score -2):

```js
const middlePoints = '{"Adana, Türkiye","Mersin, Akdeniz/Mersin, Türkiye","Yozgat, Yozgat Merkez/Yozgat, Türkiye"}'

let dataArray = middlePoints.split('","');
dataArray[0] = dataArray[0].slice(1);
dataArray[dataArray.length - 1] = dataArray[dataArray.length - 1].slice(0, -1);
const correctedData = dataArray.map(item => item.replace(/^"/, '').replace(/"$/, ''));
console.log(correctedData)
```

I used this method, but it could be the hard way. If you know a better answer, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for good comments. I did better using this 
 let d = JSON.parse(`[${data.replace(/[{}]/g, "")}]`);